# Alter a view so it adds a custom field ->textbox

Tags: views, 7, nodes, database

I have a bit specific question.

I have a content type->TESTS
it has the more or less the normal fields.

There is a view that displays all of the tests. So far,so good.

But the requirement is to add a specific textbox-> SCORE of TEST for every instance.

And it should be different for all the logged in users.

For example. All users see the tests and can insert a result.
This result is recorded in the database.

What should be the best approach doing so ?

Maybe:
1.Create the field "ScoreOfTest"
2.Alter the view in a custom module

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you create the content type does it reference who test scores they are? Without any reference's to who's score it is this would be hard. You could use entities I believe as you can create relationships you need then you could use views to display it.

http://drupal.org/node/1261744

Comment: Hi..with some delay... 

The scope of the project required a custom module...
And I am working on it now..
Anyhow,thanks a lot